# Where to put Database, Router, and similar classes in PHP folder structure

Tags: php, database, architecture, directory-structure

I am creating my own Application, without a framework, and can't seem to find any answers for this that aren't framework related. I'm also using GoogleAppEngine, just in case that matters for some reason. My folder structure is currently this:

```
root/
├── MyApp/ 
│   ├── Config/
│   │   ├── config.php
│   │   └── routes.json
│   ├── Controller/
│   ├── Layout/
│   ├── Library/
│   │   ├── Exception/
│   │   ├── Router.php
│   │   └── Database.php
│   ├── Model/
│   │   ├── Entity/ 
│   │   ├── Repository/
│   │   └── Service/
├── system/ 
│   ├── config/
│   ├── language/
│   ├── Library/
│   ├── Plugins/
│   └── scripts/
├── static/ 
│   ├── css/
│   ├── images/
│   └── js/
├── temp
├── tests
├── app.yaml
├── index.php
├── env.php
└── .htaccess
```

This is more of an architectural opinion, but I would like some guidance on where to put my Database, Router, Route, RouteFactory, etc. classes. Is the Library folder for this purpose, or is another place more logical? If someone else has to takeover my application, I don't want them running around looking for things. Also, any other critiques to my folder structure are welcome. Always learning =). Thanks in advance!

Comment: Lib, Library, Core. Mostly semantics. Anywhere it is easily recognizable and linked with your autoloading function.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Write documentation explaining your business logic, classes etc. For me, although writing app in PHP, I tend to arrange things similar to .NET MVC. Personal preference though.

Comment: @frz3993 Don't know much about .NET. I was coding in Ruby before, which does a lot of the thinking for you when it comes to folder structure among other things, so if you both think it doesn't seem blatantly "wrong" I'm okay with that. =)